# Pine Script Color Bar on Highest Numer - RSI

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='RSI - In-Out V.3', overlay=true, shorttitle='RSI-In-Out V.3')
src = low
len = input.int(18, minval=1, title='Length')
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)

float v01 = request.security('', timeframe.period, src, barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_on)
bool show_v01 = input(title='RSI Number Per Bar', defval=true)

rsiDXY = ta.rsi(v01, 14)

numBars = 1

t = rsiDXY
x = str.format("{0,number,0.0}", rsiDXY)

if t == t[1]
    numBars := nz(numBars[1]) 
    numBars

else
    numBars := 1
    numBars

label.new(bar_index,close,str.tostring(x),textcolor =     color.green,style=label.style_none,size=size.normal,yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```

How can I lookback and change the color of the Bar that has the Highest or Lowest Number?
Example:  Highest bar was 85 on RSI, that Bar would be Yellow.
Example:  Lowest bar print 21 on the RSI, that bar would be orange.
All other bars stay the same defaut color

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, however it won't change the color back to regular if a new bar is higher, so you will have multiple yellow bars

```
rsi = ta.rsi(close,14)
highestRSI = ta.highest(rsi,10)
checkHigh = rsi == highestRSI
barcolor(checkHigh ? color.yellow : na)
```